# JavaScript external file does not show variables

Tags: javascript

Well I am pretty new at javascript. Problem is
when I write stuff , for example a variable or array in an external js file, and embed it with  , VStudio 2008 intellisense does not show any of the variables ... is it because I cannot access to variables in one script tag from another? if so How do I use jQuery like stuff? .. I defined an array in a js file, embedded it, but the intellisense does not show it ... it s a problem with the intellisense i think, is it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like an intellisense issue.  To the web page, anything that is globally defined in javascript should be accessible in any script tag on the page or any included file, again so long as it is within the correct variable scope.

Overall I haven't been very impressed with VStudio's ability to do intellisense, but I haven't really seen any IDE do well with intellisense for javascript.

Comment: why do you think it is? Javascript is C like language , in its syntax, but has powerfull stuff that AI languages has, like plugging functions into each other .. I need to get a feel of the platform .. Can you help me in that, maybe leading me to read some specific stuff???
thx in advance

Comment: When manipulating the DOM, the issue is that all the browsers have a slightly different view of the DOM, so attributes are different and things behave in strange ways, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766/how-do-you-get-javascript-jquery-intellisense-working-in-vs-2008