# VS Intellisense not predicting things with JavaScript libraries

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense

When I include a JavaScript library with my normal script, is there a way to make Visual Studio (2015)'s Intellisense work?

My setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- the library I want Intellisense to work with -->
    <script src="libs/three/build/three.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in my `main.js` I want to use the Three library I have specified:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

When I enter `THREE.` I want to see a list of available attributes as I begin typing `Scene`.

Is my setup wrong - do I need some sort of config file? Or does this functionality not exist with JS?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here, in another SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766/how-do-you-get-javascript-jquery-intellisense-working-in-visual-studio-2008?rq=1) Go and vote on it instead of this one.

For anyone else reading this: include this line at the top of your external JavaScript file:

```
/// <reference path="myLibrary.js"/>
```

So in my case, in my `main.js`, I would have

```
/// <reference path="libs/three/build/three.min.js"/>
```